# Home theater audio setup for a projector

Tags: home-theater, audio, projector

I have a projector (Optoma EH336) and want to buy a relatively inexpensive home theater set up for audio. I will be pushing content from a USB device or a laptop, placed close to the projector. Of course, though, the central speaker would be on the opposite wall (where the image gets projected).

Since I'd like to avoid running a cable between the back and front walls I was wondering if anyone here knows about a wireless home theater that has the input connections in the rear speakers or subwoofer instead of in the central/front one? That way, I can run a cable on the same side of the room instead of having to cross it (and the home theater's wireless can do the rest by transfering the audio to the front speaker).

I've been reading about bluetooth home theaters too, but (1) neither my projector or source device have bluetooth, and (2) even if I get an optical-to-bluetooth dongle I don't think I'd have many degrees of freedom to control video or audio delays so as to avoid lip sync (the projector or the source device don't have the option for video delay at least in their respective menus).

I know my question is a bit vague but I'd appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction.

Thanks!!
Francisco

Comment: use a chromecast audio

Comment: Chromecast is two channel.  Klipsch has an entirely wireless system.  I'm not putting it in an answer because the Center bar is $600, the Sub is $700, the transmitter is $300, etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

Running speaker wires is *not* hard. Because they are low voltage, they are not subject to the same safey-based constraints as regular AC "mains" wiring. You can run them externally along baseboards, around corners, etc. without having to protect with conduit, etc. The only thing you *can't* do is to run them through the same conduit, junction boxes, etc. that you use for regular AC wiring.

While wireless connections have come a *long* way, I still prefer wired when *practical*. To me that includes any reasonably permanent installation - whether for AV equipment (like your speakers) or for computer network connections. Give me wired Ethernet over WiFi any day. (And a static IP instead of DHCP while we're at it. But I digress.)

Comment: Thanks, and I'll definitely run the wires if needed. But at this point I'm looking to see if alternatives exist. I'd rather avoid running the wires not due to an inability to do so but more for aesthetic purposes (I'm definitely not going to be running the wires *inside* the wall). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

"Relatively inexpensive" is not compatible with "entirely wireless".  The answer to the question as you framed it is, no.

Forget bluetooth, you'll never get that in sync.

If you're playing from a laptop you'll need at least a theater receiver that takes USB or optical input and converts to multichannel output for the speakers.  You can't just plug rears and subs into a projector's audio out.

If cost is some part of your objective, wireless should not be.  You ought to put every penny into sound quality and only start with wireless when money is no longer a consideration.

**EDIT** -- have you considered designer surface mount conduit?  There are  attractive and paintable kinds, some  that blend into your baseboard.   For $100 or $200 you can solve the aesthetic requirement by hiding the cables, and free up a TON of money to get a better system that is easier to use.